# Javascript - How to extract filename from a file input control Mozilla Browser Issue

Tags: javascript

Javascript - How to extract filename from a file input control

```
 if (filename.indexOf('\\') === 0 || filename.indexOf('/') === 0) {
      filename = filename.substring(1, filename.lastIndexOf('.'));
      if(filename != productCategoryId){
```

It worked me in google browser but in mozilla its getting error showing extension also like .jpg again

Ex: 14030501.jpg in mozilla having issue 14030501 in google with out issue.

I should not get that .jpg in mozilla.

Comment: `console.log(filename)` before your code ... what does it show

Comment: filename "14030501" in chrome & "14030501.jpg" in mozilla plz assist

Comment: that's because in firefox the first character isn't a `/` - so it never trims the extension off

Comment: what to do plz help it should work in both mozilla & chrome

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
if (filename.indexOf('\\') === 0 || filename.indexOf('/') === 0) {
      filename = filename.substring(1, filename.lastIndexOf('.'));
}
else {
      filename = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf('.'));
}
if(filename != productCategoryId){
```

Comment: Thanks it works on both mozilla & chrome ..Thanks a lot for ur help